# IE long-pooling with suspended connection XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, comet, long-polling

I have a nice problem.

I have an application that suspend the request and stream data.  The client will be IE6+ using long-polling.

With IE6 the XMLHttpRequest response data is only available in state==4.  because my application is suspending the request for streaming data, I won't received state==4 until I resume the request, so I'll be stuck in state==3.

in Firefox or Chrome if I do abort() in state==3, it will switch to state==4 and quit nicely, but in IE, if I do abort(), the state will become ==0. and I'll never be in state==4.

I though of using a timeout, but look like the timeout doesn't exist in IE.

EDIT

I think, I can fix the problem, by passing a resumetimeout attribut in the request and create a timer in the server that will resume the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a Runnable in the server that will resume the request fix the limitation of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time butting up against this problem a while ago, and I came to the realisation that IE will start returning data as downloading occurs after a threshold amount (I think it was 512 bytes) has been downloaded.  So if you just send some quantity of padding at the start of your response, IE then starts behaving the same as other browsers.